# ClickOnce deployment and download

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have an application which is of almost 150 mb, most of them them are DLLs. On a particular version-update, how can i Identify the list of all files downloaded for the version-update.

Because the update-window always shows 150 mb. But download history says only 44 mb. I just want to know what are all the files getting download. Is there any possibility to identify it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can open up the **YourApplication.exe.manifest** file. This file is version dependent and placed in a subfolder of the one-click install. The manifest file contains the meta-data that identifies which file will get patched/installed on the target machine.

Comment: If you want to reduce the size of the deployment you can always remove the older versions folders. It is an incremental update. If you know that you don't have to support a certain version then you can delete that version and below.